# ClassCastException upon casting object to its own type

Tags: java

I got a `ClassCastException` upon casting an object of type Node to a DatanodeDescriptor.
When I examine the object in the debugger it is of type DatanodeDescriptor and contains valid data. What could be the problem?

```
Node n = null;
...
...
n = innerNode.getLeaf(index, null);
DatanodeDescriptor d = (DatanodeDescriptor)n;
```

EDIT: I added a line to check

```
if (n instanceof DatanodeDescriptor)System.out.println("It is")
```

and it printed successfully before it gave the exception

Comment: Did you do an `if(n instanceof DatanodeDescriptor)` , and checked the result ?

Comment: What was the detail message, e.g. `{someType} cannot be cast to DatanodeDescriptor`?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology$InnerNode cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DatanodeDescriptor

Comment: @gparyani: What is a class loader? And how do I solve this problem if it is because of class loaders

Comment: Time to read up on class loaders then. The oracle tutorial is quite good.

Comment: "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology$InnerNode cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DatanodeDescriptor" Yeah so exactly what I said in my answer... what makes you think that InnerNode is a DatanodeDescriptor? Originally you said NODE is a DatanodeDescriptor...

Comment: You have to print out your instanceof check AFTER you call the getLeaf method. Something tells me you didn't do that.

Comment: I did print the check after the getLeaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either innerNode.getLeaf doesn't return a DatanodeDescriptor or Node isn't actually a DatanodeDescriptor.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is full determind by the package. Are you sure that DatanodeDescriptor are really the same classes? You might consider using the interface for casting insgtread of the class name.

to illjustrate it i.e.

```
my.node.Node;
other.node.Node;

Node nd = (Node)other;
```

Comment: What about class loaders? Casting to a class loaded from a different class loader (even though it is the same class) will result in a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.